# MySQL Error 1215 Foreign Key Issue

Tags: mysql, key

Trying to figure out why im getting a 1215 error with my code. I've searched the threads, looked at a whole bunch of and tried the 'solutions'  that have worked for other people, but i cant seem to apply such fixes to my code. Code as follows(edit put my entire code in):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ERUS30114465;

USE ERUS30114465;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee
(
EmployeeID int(15),
PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID),
FirstName varchar(40),
LastName varchar(40),
DateStarted date,
TaxNum int(9),
StoreID int(15)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Store
(
StoreID int(15),
PRIMARY KEY(StoreID),
Name varchar(40),
Email varchar(60),
Phone int(10),
Fax int(20),
StoreManager int(15),
SupervisingStoreID int(15),
FOREIGN KEY(SupervisingStoreID) REFERENCES Store(StoreID)   
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artist
(
ArtistID int(25),
PRIMARY KEY(ArtistID),
FirstName varchar(40),
LastName varchar(40),
DOB date,
Website varchar(255)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category
(
CategoryID char(1) PRIMARY KEY,
Description varchar(255)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CD
(
CDNumber int(8),
CategoryID char(1),
Length int(6),
NumberOfTracks int(8),
ReleaseDate date,
ReorderLevel int(8), 
Title varchar (255),
PRIMARY KEY(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(CategoryID) REFERENCES Category(CategoryID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CDArtist
(
ArtistID int(25),
CDNumber int(8),    
FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID) REFERENCES Artist(ArtistID),
FOREIGN KEY(CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Transactions
(
TransactionID int(25),
TransDate date,
StoreNumber int(15),   
PRIMARY KEY(TransactionID),
FOREIGN KEY(StoreNumber) REFERENCES Store(StoreID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TransactionDetails
(
CDNumber int(8),
TransactionID int(25),
Quantity int(8),
Discount int(2),
FOREIGN KEY (CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (TransactionID) REFERENCES Transactions (TransactionID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Inventory
(
CDNumber int(8),
StoreID int(15),
QuantityOnHand int(8),
QuantityOnOrder int(8),
FOREIGN KEY (CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (StoreID) REFERENCES Store(StoreID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Address
(
Tid char(1),
PRIMARY KEY(Tid),
AddressID int(30),
AddressType varchar(60),
FOREIGN KEY(AddressType) REFERENCES AddressType(AddressType),
Street varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
State varchar(255)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AddressType
(
AddressType varchar(60), 
PRIMARY KEY (AddressType),
Description varchar(255)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer
(
CustomerID int(25),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID),
FirstName varchar(60),
LastName varchar(60), 
Phone int(10)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CDPrice
(
EffectiveFrom date,
Price int(5),
Reason varchar(255),
CDNumber int(8),
PRIMARY KEY(EffectiveFrom),
FOREIGN KEY(CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CustomerOrder
(
CustomerOrderID int(25),
OrderDate date,
StoreID int(15),
CustomerID int(25),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerOrderID), 
FOREIGN KEY(StoreID) REFERENCES Store(StoreID),
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderDetails
(
CDNumber int(8),
CustomerOrderID int(25),
DateArrived date,
DatePickedUp date,
Quantity int(8),
FOREIGN KEY(CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerOrderID) REFERENCES CustomerOrder(CustomerOrderID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`"#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint "`

Said error is (now) in relation to the last table `OrderDetails`

If its staring me in the face, i cant see it -_- ive been working on the bigger data base for about 16 hours straight....

any help greatly appreciated :D

Comment: if you make modifications to your tables and run these `create table if not exists`, you may by mistake NOT recreate a table that has changed. It's `create table if not exists`, not `alter table if different`

Comment: Put addressType table before address http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98d01

Answer (score 1):

Basically **DATE** is a reserved keyword of MYSQL

IF YOU want to use you can try using the backtick like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Transaction`
(
TransactionID int(25),
`Date` date,
StoreNumber int(15),   
PRIMARY KEY(TransactionID),
FOREIGN KEY(StoreNumber) REFERENCES Store(StoreID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TransactionDetails
(
CDNumber int(8),
TransactionID int(25),
Quantity int(8),
Discount int(2),
FOREIGN KEY (CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (TransactionID) REFERENCES `Transaction`(TransactionID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: I thing Date field also is a reserved keyword of MYSQL

Comment: Tried the backtick and i got the same error, but after you discussed TRANSACTION being a reserved word, i tried changing Transaction -> Transactions as follows:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Transactions
(
TransactionID int(25),
Date date,
StoreNumber int(15),   
PRIMARY KEY(TransactionID),
FOREIGN KEY(StoreNumber) REFERENCES Store(StoreID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

and that worked great, though ill change 'Date' as well, thanks guys

Comment: @user2915539, have you checked that the Transaction and Transactions table are identical?

Answer (score 1):

Transaction is not a reserved word,at least in 5.5 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

I removed the foreign key reference to store table in the transaction table and it worked.Are you sure you didn't forget to create the store table?Or if exist make sure both column are the same type and size,and both tables have the same engine

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c82c

Comment: getting the same error on my last table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CustomerOrder
(
CustomerOrderID int(25),
OrderDate date,
StoreID int(15),
CustomerID int(25),
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerOrderID), 
FOREIGN KEY(StoreID) REFERENCES Store(StoreID),
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderDetails
(
CDNumber int(8),
CustomerOrderID int(25),
DateArrived date,
DatePickedUp date,
Quantity int(8),
FOREIGN KEY(CDNumber) REFERENCES CD(CDNumber),
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerOrderID) REFERENCES CustomerOrder(CustomerOrderID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
not sure?

Comment: @user2915539 Make sure the table and column referenced exist.

Comment: @Mihai as far as i can tell they are :/

Comment: @user2915539 Post ALL you tables in the original post,its hard to scroll up and down checking fields and point where your error is.

Comment: @Mihai have done, 1215 errors have started popping up for other tables as well, its really doing my head in :/